# Should "Impl" naming always be avoided?

Tags: coding-style, naming, coding-standards

When implementing interfaces, as a general rule, `Impl` is evil. Ok, but is it evil in the following case?

I've a service that has (and probably will have) only one implementation. In such case, normally I don't need any interface. But, the "contract" must be shared with other modules because the service is exposed using [`HttpInvokerServiceExporter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-httpinvoker). And the client, needs the interface to dynamically buid a proxy to do the remote invocation:

```
<bean id="stockService" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://HOST:1199/StockService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="example.StockService"/> <!-- Interface needed here -->
</bean>
```

This is the only reason why the api is shared. To expose the service. The client should not have the implementation classes as dependency.

In such scenario I'm thinking in a project layout like:

```
- stock-service        (project)
|- stock-service-api   (shared interfaces module)
\- stock-service-impl  (implementation module)
```

so that, `other-service` can have `stock-service-api` as dependency.

Should, "-impl" naming also be avoided in this case?
If yes, what would be a good alternative?

Comment: _"I've a service that has [...] only one implementation"_ and _"other modules need the contract to build proxys"_ are contradictory. Your case doesn't seem strong enough to warrant using `Impl`, but since you haven't provided any information on what the implementation does, no one can suggest anything worthwhile.

Comment: @VincentSavard I've edited the question. The "proxy" is a remote invoker automatically build from the interface. There will not be another "real" implementation. The stock-service is only an example. We can assume that it only has one method `getProductStock(productId)` that makes a query to a database.

Comment: Then you got your name. You have a `PostgresStockService`, or whatever your DBMS is. You have an implementation which is tied to a particular service or a particular technology, therefore it makes sense to name it as such.

Comment: arent there namespaces for this kimd of problem?

Comment: @VincentSavard I will think about it. Thinking about tied technology or architecture, probably I can find a discriminator.

Comment: @Ewan Do yo mean something like `example.api.StockService` for the interface and `example.StockService` for the implementation?

Comment: @Tobias I am unfamiliar with whatever framework this is. But yes, they are different libraries and surely should have different name spaces in whatever naming convention you are using even if one of them just has example.interfaces.*

Comment: Whatever framework or language OP uses, it seems really weird to have a `class StockService implements StockService`

Comment: how about class StockService implements MyProject.Interfaces.StockService ?

Comment: What do you think if I change interface name to `StockServiceApi`? Resulting in `class StockService implements StockServiceApi`. And, the modules of the project could be `stock-service-api` (producing the artifact stock-service-api.jar shared as dependency for other projects) and `stock-service` (the real service implementation).

Comment: @Tobías It seems quite poor. I still have no clue what's the particularity of the concrete class. Is there any reason why you dislike the idea of naming it according to your database technology?

Comment: @Ewan I guess it may come down to a question of personal preferences, but that honestly seems extremely weird to me. The name of an interface is the name of the abstraction. The name of the concrete class is the name of the implementation. If the implementation and the abstraction have the same name, why have an abstraction at all?

Comment: @VincentSavard I don't dislike it. The tech discriminator is a solution I can really use. I'm only curious about other alternatives that come to my mind. If they could be also valid or not.

Comment: @vincentsavard well, so you have an abstraction! it not just about naming. Im used to c# where we prefix interfaces with I so v common to have the same name with and I on the front

Answer (score 4):

Even if your service has only one implementation in the foreseeable future, think of some  alternative way to implement it, to help you identify something special about your actual implementation. Then, use that special "something" to name it.

Failing that, use "stock-service" for the interface and "standard-stock-service" or "default-stock-service" for the implementation.

Comment: Other options are 'Basic' or 'Simple' for general use case implementations.  'Implementation' or 'Impl' describes any concrete class.

Comment: Personally, this just feels like a workaround to avoid suffixing `Impl`. Prefixing `Standard` or `Default` does not describe in any way how the interface may behave or may be implemented. I'm sure there are some situations where it makes sense, but to me, it feels like a last resort option.